# Can't withdraw from Crowdsale multiple times

Tags: transactions, addresses, crowdsale

I'm using a crowdsale contract (listed below) and on Ropsten network I just set founding goal to 1ETH send it to crowdsale address and then I can withdraw to beneficiary address but when I send ETH a second time I can't withdraw it anymore.

I find myself in need of a Crowdsale code where I can withdraw founds anytime or a way to automatically send ETH from crowdsale to ETH address just like someone sends 1 ETH to crowdsale:

- That person receives Tokens
- Crowdsale sends that ETH to specific ETH address
- Owner of that address can withdraw anytime needed / multiple times

Here's the code I'm trying to use but only 1st withdrawal works (second stucks)

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.18;

interface token {
    function transfer(address receiver, uint amount) external;
}

contract Crowdsale {
    address public beneficiary;
    uint public fundingGoal;
    uint public amountRaised;
    uint public price;
    token public tokenReward;
    mapping(address => uint256) public balanceOf;
    bool fundingGoalReached = false;


    event GoalReached(address recipient, uint totalAmountRaised);
    event FundTransfer(address backer, uint amount, bool isContribution);

    /**
     * Constructor function
     *
     * Setup the owner
     */
    constructor(
        address ifSuccessfulSendTo,
        uint fundingGoalInEthers,

        uint milietherCostOfEachToken,
        address addressOfTokenUsedAsReward
    ) public {
        beneficiary = ifSuccessfulSendTo;
        fundingGoal = fundingGoalInEthers * 1 ether;

        price = milietherCostOfEachToken * 0.0001 ether;
        tokenReward = token(addressOfTokenUsedAsReward);
    }

    /**
     * Fallback function
     *
     * The function without name is the default function that is called whenever anyone sends funds to a contract
     */
    function () payable public {

        uint amount = msg.value;
        balanceOf[msg.sender] += amount;
        amountRaised += amount;
        tokenReward.transfer(msg.sender, amount * 10**18 / price);
       emit FundTransfer(msg.sender, amount, true);
    }


    /**
     * Check if goal was reached
     *
     * Checks if the goal or time limit has been reached and ends the campaign
     */
    function checkGoalReached() public  {
        if (amountRaised >= fundingGoal){
            fundingGoalReached = true;
            emit GoalReached(beneficiary, amountRaised);
        }

    }


    /**
     * Withdraw the funds
     *
     * Checks to see if goal or time limit has been reached, and if so, and the funding goal was reached,
     * sends the entire amount to the beneficiary. If goal was not reached, each contributor can withdraw
     * the amount they contributed.
     */
    function safeWithdrawal() public  {
        if (!fundingGoalReached) {
            uint amount = balanceOf[msg.sender];
            balanceOf[msg.sender] = 0;
            if (amount > 0) {
                if (msg.sender.send(amount)) {
                   emit FundTransfer(msg.sender, amount, false);
                } else {
                    balanceOf[msg.sender] = amount;
                }
            }
        }

        if (fundingGoalReached && beneficiary == msg.sender) {
            if (beneficiary.send(amountRaised)) {
               emit FundTransfer(beneficiary, amountRaised, false);
            } else {
                //If we fail to send the funds to beneficiary, unlock funders balance
                fundingGoalReached = false;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To automaticaly send funds to beneficiary address you can use `transfer`

```
function () payable public {

    uint amount = msg.value;
    balanceOf[msg.sender] += amount;
    amountRaised += amount;
    tokenReward.transfer(msg.sender, amount * 10**18 / price);
    emit FundTransfer(msg.sender, amount, true);

    // Forward funds immediately to beneficiary
    beneficiary.transfer(amount);
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to deploy contract using mist on osx - it worked fine on testnet but when i try to do it on main net the transaction just hangs on information "Couldn't estimate gas, restoring to default parameters. Transaction is likely cheaper than the estimate"

I have deployed token contract using byte code and MEW before but in this contract i need to provide

token address used as reward token price beneficiary address

and i just don't know how to do it using remix and bytecode

Comment: solved, problem was that ....uhmmmm I'm stupid ;)